How to move the cursor above the first line without overighting it
Here is my code
print("1")
print("2")


My desired output
2
1

I tried using ansi characters but the second line is overighting the first line

print("1")
print("\033[3A2")  

output
2

How can I achieve my desired output using other means apart from loop to reverse the order of the print statement
I prefer ansi characters, terminal(), but I will also use other methods

Does this answer your question? Python Print Order

it is not possible to do this. The print order is sequential. The best one can do is write over the existing line (in the Terminal).

The obvious thing to do is switch the two lines around so why isn't that possible? How is the first print call supposed to know there will be subsequent calls?

To achieve the visual effect of printing a new line at the top while moving previous lines downwards, you can keep the previous lines in a list and print them in reverse order when printing a new line.
Before printing a new line though, you need to move the cursor up for however many previous lines there are by using the <ESC>[{count}A control code. Use the <ESC>[K control code to clear from the current cursor position to the end of the current line to erase any leftover characters from a longer previous line:
def reverse_print_factory(print=print):
    def _print(line):
        if lines:
            print(f'\033[{len(lines)}A', end='')
        lines.append(line)
        for line in reversed(lines):
            print(f'{line}\033[K')
    lines = []
    return _print

print = reverse_print_factory()

so that:
from time import sleep

for text in 'first', 'second', 'third':
    print(text)
    sleep(1)

would produce the following output on a VT100/ANSI-compatible terminal:
first

and then after a second:
second
first

and then after another second:
third
second
first

EDIT: A more efficient (but slightly less portable because of the need to control the standard input) approach would be to scroll up the region of the previous lines so you don't have to store previous lines in a list.
This can be done by using the <ESC>[{start row};{end row}r control code to set the scrollable region, move the cursor to the top of the region with the <ESC>[{row};{column}f control code, and then using the <ESC>M control code to scroll up, effectively moving the lines in the region downwards.
To obtain the starting row, you can use the <ESC>[6n control code to query the cursor position and then read the response from standard input in the <ESC>[{row};{column}R format. This has been helpfully written into the cursorPos function in this answer, which I'm using in the following example:
def reverse_print_factory(print=print):
    def _print(text):
        nonlocal count
        if count:
            print(f'\033[{start_row};{start_row + count}r\033[{start_row};1f\033M', end='')
        count += 1
        print(f'{text}\033[K\033[{start_row + count};1f', flush=True, end='')    
    start_row = int(cursorPos()[1])
    count = 0
    return _print

print = reverse_print_factory()

To further account for lines that reach the height of the terminal (obtainable with shutil.get_terminal_size), you can move the lines before the starting row upwards (with the <ESC>D control code) to make way for the new line instead of moving the previous lines downwards, until the entire screen is filled with output, at which point move the entire screen downwards again to make way for the new line at the top.
Also use atexist.register to register an exit handler that resets the scrollable region to the entire screen and outputs an additional newline if the lines have reached the terminal height to prevent the command prompt from unnecessarily overwriting the last line of output:
import shutil
import atexit

def reverse_print_factory(print=print):
    def _print(text):
        nonlocal start_row, count
        if count:
            if 1 < start_row > height - count:
                print(f'\033[1;{start_row - 1}r\033[{start_row - 1};1f\033D\033[{start_row - 1};1f', end='')
                start_row -= 1
            else:
                print(f'\033[{start_row};{start_row + count}r\033[{start_row};1f\033M', end='')
        count += 1
        print(f'{text}\033[K\033[{start_row + count};1f', flush=True, end='')
    def _exit():
        print(f'\033[r\033[{start_row + count};1f', end='')
        if 1 < start_row > height - count:
            print()
    height = shutil.get_terminal_size()[1]
    start_row = int(cursorPos()[1])
    count = 0
    atexit.register(_exit)
    return _print

print = reverse_print_factory()

Note that a complete set of VT100 control sequences can be found at:
https://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html

Wrong tool for the job (see my answer). Works in the simplest cases. Breaks if the output is taller than the terminal's height. Breaks if a line is longer than the terminal's width (or equally as wide; \e[K loves to chop off the last character then). You cannot redirect the output in a meaningful way. You can't fix these breakages if you keep the overall approach; terminals just weren't designed for this kind of operation. If you're okay with remembering (and re-printing) the earlier lines, why not just batch them up in memory and print them only once, in the end, in the proper order?

The fact that the OP's attempt uses ANSI code tells me that the OP's more interested in the visual presentation on the terminal while the lines are being sent to the output, or else the OP would've simply output the lines in reverse order, which is explicitly excluded by the OP as a possiblity.

Could be, but in that case OP probably needs ncurses or so, putting proper thoughts into how it needs to behave with overlong lines, too many lines etc.

Actually I find this one working.It solved the day

@egmont This answer is meant as a simple proof of concept. The OP can ask a new question with more specific requirements such as handlers for line wrapping and screen scrolling if it becomes an issue for the OP. ncurses is usually the wrong tool for the job of line-based output because it requires clearing the screen first with initscr.

@CharlesWabochi I've updated the answer with a more efficient solution using a scrollable region instead.

@blhsing My point is that while this answer works for the very simplest cases, it does not scale and it cannot be fixed to scale to slightly more complex scenarios. That being said, if OP is looking for a quick hack for personal use that works in the simplest cases and does not scale then okay. If the code is to be released to and used by a wider audience, or ever used for more than a handful of short lines then absolutely no. It's not a clean, maintainable solution by any means, it's as dirty of a hack as it can be. And the problem is not with the exact code lines, but the concept behind.

@egmont What I've demonstrated is exactly the concept behind how the OP's basic goal can be achieved, which the OP has validated in the comment above. If the OP's goal could be achieved with ncurses or any existing library I would've recommended them instead, but there simply is none that I'm aware of, which is why I showcased a basic implementation of the concept. Of course there are going to be edge cases that need to be ironed out before the code can reach production, but it gives a workable foundation that the OP can build on.

@egmont I'm not sure what makes you think my answer can't scale with addtional fixes and guardrails. Things like text wrap and bottom scrolling can be easily implemented with addtional computations and conditional outputs. I just don't feel like complicating the code demo unless the OP specifically asks for it.

The scrollback buffer is broken if you output more than a screenful of text; in order to fix that you'd need to be able to walk back past the top of the regular area into the scrollback and modify that which isn't possible in terminals. To handle wrapped text you need to dive into the business of locales, character widths (which terminals don't fully agree on and keeps changing with Unicode versions), wrapping of double width chars (which some terminals get wrong). Also you'd need to handle if the user resizes the terminal, without even knowing whether the terminal reflows earlier contents.

@egmont It is highly unlikely that there is any real-world use case for outputting a single line of text that's more than a screenful. There are well-maintained libraries that keep track of the widths of Unicode characters. One cannot accomplish anything if only perfection is good enough. Good enough is perfectly good enough.

I'm not talking about a single line being more than a screenful. I'm talking about a line being wider than the screen, or the entire output being taller than a screen. Both are absolutely reasonable. Sure, keep coding in a way that breaks as soon as you hit these pretty low limits if that's your kind of thing.

@egmont Once again a single line that's wider than the width of terminal can be easily be broken into two or more lines providing of course that the widths of the characters are properly accounted for. It isn't that hard. I just don't feel like including it in this answer to avoid obscuring the core logics. Feel free to take my core logics and make it production ready.

Computing the number of visual lines for a logical line is doable (assuming the library and the terminal agree on the widths), although more complicated than just a division, it should take into account double-wide chars that just don't fit in the last column and thus cause an early wrap. And then you still didn't handle window resizes (you cannot because you don't know if the terminal reflows the lines or not, also there' a race condition if you resize the window just when the related computations take place)...

... and you still haven't handled if the number of lines printed is larger than the terminal's height (I don't even know what the desired behavior is in this case, but it easily can be one that's literally unachievable in terminals, unless you print the lines in their desired final visual order). I know that your approach can not be made into production-ready robust code. It's a simple hack that only works with very small amounts of data.

@egmont None of the line-based (non-full-screen) visual libraries (such as those that handle progress bar and readline) account for windows resizes. That's just a known limitation. Handling number of lines larger than the terminal's height is easy since the terminal size can be pre-determined and one just needs to limit the scrollable region once the terminal height is reached. Plenty of libraries that do progress bars and readline have demonstrated that already. Calling escape sequences a hack is absurd.

Don't you think it's desired to end up with a terminal that contains all the output from the app, in reverse order? Some being in the scrollback buffer if necessary. ... Let's just conclude that it's highly unspecified how the original question intends to scale to slightly larger outputs and we had vastly different expectations there.

@egmont No, I think the actual use cases for this kind of reverse output are much more likely to treat the screen as a FIFO, where the content is transient and is perfectly OK to get dropped once out of sight, and only the most recent screenful of output gets displayed. One can obviously implement a scrollback buffer if actually needed, but it will always be an unessential feature.

But then wouldn't the regular order (most recent messages at the bottom) suffice? ... I don't know ... We both made arbitrary (and different) expectations rather than asking OP for clarification. We don't know the timing of events. We don't know the amount and characteristics of the data. We don't know if they need to persist. We don't know why reversing the order in the app isn't a good solution. We don't know if ncurses is a viable alternative. We don't know the overall use case and rationale behind the feature request.

Which is why my answer attempts to satisfy only the most basic goal outlined by the question. Unless the OP clarifies with more specific further requirements (with a new question per the SO rules) I won't attempt to unnessarily complicate my demo code with features not asked for.

@egmont I've updated my answer with code that handles lines that reach the terminal height, which I think is indeed a common enough scenario even though the OP doesn't specifically ask for it.

Thank you very much,you have given me all the information that I really needed.I'm very grateful for you assistance.You are a real master of python

The problem in your code is that the "ANSI" codes are still considered has characters and are interpreted when printed / flushed.
So if you want to move from N rows / columns, you should first use the move instruction and then (and only then / when the print occured) print the characters you want.
At least that's what I usually do and I never had any troubles with it.

And if I remind good I already achieved to do that once (what you're trying to do) and I didn't had to rewrite / save everything to write it back on screen after moving the cursor

Trying to ask the terminal to reorder the lines this way is a conceptually wrong approach. Forget it.
Modify the business logic of your application to output the lines in the desired final order (from the top, going downwards).
This might require to keep some data in memory for later use, rather than outputting immediately. E.g. maintain an array of lines to print, keep prepending to this array, and print it out all once when you're done with everything.

I've tried your script. The output isn't a simple 2 as you claim. The output is a 2 up there a few lines above (\033[3A moves the cursor up by 3 lines, why did you pick 3?), corrupting the output of the previous command; and a 1 down there below the new prompt that I've received. Utterly wrong in all aspect.
It's unclear to me why you move the cursor up by 3 lines rather than 1. But as you've probably noticed, moving the cursor up does not mean that newly printed lines would push the contents underneath further down.
If you want to do that (push the contents down), there is an escape sequence for that. But then if you're at the bottom of the terminal, the line that you push down will be lost for good in many terminals.
What should happen when your app finishes? If you pushed down that 1, the cursor is above it. So should the next shell prompt and every further activity keep pushing it down? Or overwrite it? Surely neither is good. You'd need to jump over it, move the cursor back to below that 1.
I'm certain that these 1 and 2 are given for the sake of example; in real life you'll have different strings. What if they are wider than the terminal and thus wrap to multiple lines, how would you know that, and how would you compute the number of lines you need to move the cursor or push the contents by?
What if your app's output is longer than the terminal's height? Terminal emulators only allow operating on the area as tall as their window; the scrollback buffer is kept for the user's convenience but is not accessible and not writeable by applications. You can absolutely not make it work if the deired output is taller than the terminal.
Lots and lots of open ended questions with many corner cases, you can go down this rabbit hole endlessly and infinitely overcomplicate your app and still not get it right.
No, it's absolutely the wrong approach. Let alone that the output cannot then be piped to another utility for further processing. Forget it. Change your application to output what it really needs to output, in its final desired order.

Of course if you're writing an app that controls the full terminal canvas and keeps changing its contents (like e.g. a text editor or a terminal-based game) then that's a whole different story. In that case you should probably use an existing terminal screen handling library.
